Asymptotic description giving a general result on interval coloring
Before I ask my question, let me give some definitions:
Definition(Interval Coloring): Let $G$ be a loopless graph. Then, a (proper) edge coloring of $G$ with $t$ colors is called an interval $t$-coloring if at any vertex of $G$, edges incident to that vertex gets consecutive colors and all $t$ colors are used.
Below, you can find an example of an interval $5$-coloring of the given graph:

Now, we can define a thickness concept, measuring how far is a graph from being interval colorable:
Definition(Interval Coloring Thickness): Let $G$ be a loopless graph. Then, interval coloring thickness of $G$ is the minimum number of edge disjoint subgraphs of $G$ such that all of them are interval colorable and their union gives $G$, denoted by $\theta_{\text{int}}(G)$.

Fact 1: For all the loopless graphs with $m$ edges, define $\theta(m)=\max\{\theta_{\text{int}}(G)\mid |E(G)|=m\}$. Then, it is proven that $$\theta(m) = \Omega\bigg(\frac{\log m}{\log(\log m)}\bigg)\text{ i.e. } \frac{\log m}{\log(\log m)} = \mathcal{O}(\theta'(m))$$
This means $\exists c \in \mathbb{R}^+, m_0 \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $\forall m > m_0$, $\dfrac{\log m}{\log(\log m)} \le c\theta(m)$.
Then, in that paper, it is stated as a corollary that, given any positive integer $k$, there is a graph $G$ with interval coloring thickness $\theta_{\text{int}}(G) = k$. And this is given without a proof or any other explanation, so I thought maybe it is something obvious if we assume Fact 1.
But I really could not come up with a justification by using the definition of $\Omega$ notation or anything else. I know that $f(m)=\Omega(g(m))$ intuitively means that $g(m)$ is a lower bound for $f(m)$ for sufficiently large $m$. And I checked the behaviour of the function $f(x) = \dfrac{\log x}{\log(\log x)}$ for real numbers and saw that $\text{Im}(f) = [e,\infty)$ whenever $x > e$. But this does not mean we can find a natural number $m$ for which $\theta(m) = k$, does it?
I should also emphasize that I am new to Big-Oh notation and computational complexity so I might be missing something very simple. Can anyone explain me how can we obtain that strong result using Fact 1? Thank you in advance.

There's no computational complexity here: this is just an asymptotic description of the growth rate of $\theta(m)$.

It's true that something else needs to be done here. The "straightforward" application of Fact 1 merely tells us that for all positive integers $k$, there is a graph $G$ with $\theta_{\text{int}}(G) \ge k$.
(Proof: first, choose $C>0$ and $N_0>0$ such that for all $m \ge N_0$, $\theta(m) \ge \frac{C\log m}{\log \log m}$. This much can be done by the definition of $\Omega$-notation. Then, choose $N_1>0$ such that $\frac{C \log m}{\log \log m} \ge k$ for all $m \ge N_1$; this can be done because $f(x) = \frac{\log x}{\log \log x}$ is an increasing function that goes to $\infty$ as $x \to \infty$. Now if we set $m = \max\{N_0, N_1\}$, we can use both inequalities and conclude $\theta(m) \ge k$, so in particular there is an $m$-edge graph $G$ with $\theta_{\text{int}}(G) = \theta(m) \ge k$.)
After this proof is done, we're still left with a potential problem: what if there's some value of $k$ such that $\theta_{\text{int}}(G)$ can be bigger than $k$, but never equal to $k$?

Here is a lemma that helps us address this concern.
Lemma. Let $G$ be any graph. Then $G$ has an edge $e$ such that $$\theta_{\text{int}}(G) - 1 \le \theta_{\text{int}}(G-e) \le \theta_{\text{int}}(G).$$ (Here, $G-e$ is the subgraph of $G$ obtained by deleting edge $e$.)
Proof. Let $k = \theta_{\text{int}}(G)$. By assumption, we can decompose $G$ into edge-disjoint subgraphs $G_1, \dots, G_k$ which are interval colorable. Let $e$ be an edge of $G_1$ which gets color $t$ in some interval $t$-coloring. Then $G_1 - e$ is still interval colorable (with either $t-1$ or $t$ colors) and so $G_1-e, G_2, \dots, G_k$ is a decomposition showing that $\theta_{\text{int}}(G-e) \le k$.
To prove that $\theta_{\text{int}}(G-e) \ge k-1$, suppose $G-e$ has a decomposition into edge-disjoint subgraphs $H_1, H_2, \dots, H_j$ which are all interval colorable. Let $H_{j+1}$ be the graph with only one edge: $e$. Then $H_1, H_2, \dots, H_{j+1}$ decompose $G$ into edge-disjoint interval colorable subgraphs, so $j+1 \ge k = \theta_{\text{int}}(G)$. Therefore this decomposition of $G-e$ (which was arbitrary) must have contained at least $k-1$ subgraphs. $\quad\square$

Let's put the pieces together. If we pick any "target" positive integer $k$, we can first find a graph $G$ with $\theta_{\text{int}}(G) \ge k$. Let $m = |E(G)|$. Then, construct a sequence $G_0, G_1, G_2, \dots, G_m$ with $G_0 = G$, where we define $G_i$ for each $i \ge 1$ by using the lemma to set $G_i = G_{i-1} - e$ so that $\theta_{\text{int}}(G_i)$ is either $\theta_{\text{int}}(G_{i-1})$ or $\theta_{\text{int}}(G_{i-1})-1$. As a result, in the sequence
$$
   \theta_{\text{int}}(G_0), \theta_{\text{int}}(G_1), \dots, \theta_{\text{int}}(G_m),
$$
each value is either the same as the previous value, or just $1$ less. However, we also know that $\theta_{\text{int}}(G_0) > k$, while $\theta_{\text{int}}(G_m) = 0 < k$ (an empty graph is made up of $0$ interval colorable pieces). Therefore, somewhere in between, there must be a graph $G_i$ with $\theta_{\text{int}}(G_i) = k$: decreasing by just $1$ each time, we can never skip $k$.

The problem here is that the Lemma you wrote is not generally true. If we consider a graph $G$ with vertex set ${a,b,c,d}$ and edge set ${ab, bc, ca, ad}$, then $G$ is interval colorable so $\theta_{\text{int}}(G)=1$ but $G-ad$ is not interval colorable and $\theta_{\text{int}}(G-ad)=2$.

@ArsenBerk You're very right - we need to be more careful! Fortunately, we don't need the lemma to be true for an arbitrary edge; just knowing that there's some edge we can delete is enough. I've edited the lemma to fix this error.

This looks very nice, now I'm convinced. Thank you very much :)
